# AppleScript и повседневные задачи

Tags: applescript, mac

Необходим инструмент для повседневных задач.
Например, программа, извлекающая внешние диски перед погружением в сон или создающая расписание, когда я нахожусь у компьютера, какие были открыты приложения и т.д.
AppleScript - это то, что мне нужно, или стоит искать что-то другое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppleScript - то что нужно. Но можно поискать и другое, этож Unix. 
Имеется у меня AppleScript на папку /Volumes как только втыкаешь флешку с пределнным именем, тут же туда делается бекап. (p.s. задача была не стандартная поэтому надо было так, так что не спрашивайте зачем и почему, просто пришлось такой скрипт писать)